# Jenkins Pipeline - emailext Does not Resolve env Variable in Template

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, email-ext

In my `jenkinsfile` I defined an environment variable:

`env.PACKAGES = htmlPackageList`

I tried accessing it from the template with `${PACKAGES}` and `${env.PACKAGES}`, but both times I just receive the email with a plain string.

**template.html**:

```
<pre style='line-height: 10px; color: green; font-size: 20px; white-space: pre; margin: 1em 0; display: block;'>$PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS.<br/> </pre>
<br/>
Check console <a href="$BUILD_URL">Build URL</a> to view full results.<br/>
<br/>
<h4>Change list:</h4>
<div style="padding-left: 30px; padding-bottom: 15px;">
    ${CHANGES, showPaths=true, format="<div><b>%a</b>: %r %p </div><div style=\"padding-left:30px;\"> &#8212; &#8220;<em>%m</em>&#8221;</div>", pathFormat="</div><div style=\"padding-left:30px;\">%p"}
</div>
--<br/>

<h4>Published Packages:</h4>
${PACKAGES}
```

The email is invoked by:

```
success {
    script{
        emailext body: ('${FILE,path="Jenkins/Templates/template.html"}'),
        to: "${env.EmailTo}",
        subject: '[Jenkins] [$PROJECT_NAME] - [Build # $BUILD_NUMBER] - [$BUILD_STATUS]',
        mimeType: 'text/html'
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show how you pass the variable to the email?

Comment: I don't actually pass it, I just defined the `env.PACKAGES` and thought I could use it in the template.

Comment: Ok then can you provide the code where you use this template in your Jenkinsfile?

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: Thanks! I just can't find your PACKAGES variable. Where do you pass it? Maybe this is your issue - Have a look: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. I don't pass the variable, I defined a custom environment variable and called it `PACKAGES`. And based on what I read, the template can access the environment variables previously defined, maybe I got it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The below declaration in template(groovy) can fetch all the env variables from pipeline

```
<% def envEnviron = it.getAction("org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl").getEnvironment()
    println(envEnviron)
%\>
```

The below also can be used to get only the overridden variables in pipeline

```
<% def envOveriddenEnviron = it.getAction("org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl").getOverriddenEnvironment()
    println(envOveriddenEnviron)
%\>
```

Comment: Gonna try it later today